# How can I add an arbitrary field to the wordpress sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

How to add a field in custom sidebar area on widget settings page in wordpress? This text field will be used to set the color of the container

```
<?php
function stackoverflow_template_register_wp_sidebar() {
 
  register_sidebar(
    array(
      'id' => 'stackoverflow',
      'name' => 'Demo', 
      'description' => 'Descriptiion', 
      'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side widget %2$s">', 
      'after_widget' => '</div>',
      'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">', 
      'after_title' => '</h3>'
    )
  );
 

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'stackoverflow_template_register_wp_sidebar' );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqzXP.jpg)

The widget settings page works in classic mode.